# Facebook like in IE9 doesnt snow number of likes

Tags: facebook, internet-explorer-9

Please check this url with IE9: http://www.toptrouwen.nl/
Why doesnt the like button show the number of likes (143) just like it does in Firefox?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looking at the code for that page, I see 2 potential problems.  First, the iframe has a fixed width of 80 pixels specified in 2 different locations (in the url with &width=80, and on the iframe element itself with a style="...width=80px;..." attribute.)   Second, on the facebooklike div that wraps the iframe, a fixed width of 110 is specified.  The rest of the content is hidden because the iframe has an overflow hidden set (which is fine).

Also, yes, it this issue occurs in Dutch (possibly other languages, but not English).  Facebook will use your browser language settings if you are not logged into Facebook, otherwise it will use the language of the Facebook account that is logged in.

Comment: Sorry, forgot to add: it does that (ONLY in IE!!:s) when I view the Dutch version..not sure how its determined, but the Facebook like button doesnt show 'Like', but 'Vind ik leuk' (the Dutch variant for 'like'). Is this perhaps something Facebook determines based on my url http://www.toptrouwen.nl, where the TLD is .nl?